# fechar aba usando JQUERY

Tags: php, jquery, html5

estou tentando que ao clicar no link abir abra a aba mas quando que clico abre todas teria alguma forma de quando eu clicar abrir somente a aba correspondente ao que cliquei e ao clicar novamente fechar novamente .

```html
<article class="product_category box box100" id="1">
    <span><a href='' class='j_open'> abir</a></span>
      <div class="j_open_div" style="display: none;">
        conteudo
      </div>
    </article>

    <article class="product_category box box100" id="1">
    <span><a href='' class='j_open'> abir</a></span>
      <div class="j_open_div" style="display: none;">
        conteudo
      </div>
    </article>

    <article class="product_category box box100" id="1">
    <span><a href='' class='j_open'> abir</a></span>
      <div class="j_open_div" style="display: none;">
        conteudo
      </div>
    </article>
```

```js
 
$('.j_open').on('click', function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
$('.j_open_div').slideToggle('slow');
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basta você achar o elemento `.j_open_div` dentro do `article` do link que foi clicado usando `.closest()` e `.find()`:

```js
$('.j_open').on('click', function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   $(this)                // link clicado
   .closest('article')    // busca o ancestral "article"
   .find('.j_open_div')   // busca dentro do ancestral o elemento com a classe ".j_open_div"
   .slideToggle('slow');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<article class="product_category box box100" id="1">
    <span><a href='' class='j_open'> abir</a></span>
      <div class="j_open_div" style="display: none;">
        conteudo
      </div>
    </article>

    <article class="product_category box box100" id="1">
    <span><a href='' class='j_open'> abir</a></span>
      <div class="j_open_div" style="display: none;">
        conteudo
      </div>
    </article>

    <article class="product_category box box100" id="1">
    <span><a href='' class='j_open'> abir</a></span>
      <div class="j_open_div" style="display: none;">
        conteudo
      </div>
    </article>
```

Comment: obrigado deu certinho .